# How can I get differentially expressed genes to be color coded by significance level in a volcano plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a volcano plot using ggplot2 and am trying to get upregulated genes to be red, downregulated to be blue, and non-significant to be black. I am trying to make a variable using an ifelse statement with 3 categories: up-regulated (LFC>=0.58 & FDR<=0.05), down-regulated (LFC<=0.58 & FDR<=0.05), and non-significant.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

resultggplot2.6 <- read.csv("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/R files/DH_L_vs_DH_R.de_genes.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
resultggplot2.6
pdf('volcano21.pdf')

***deg <- ifelse(resultggplot2.6$LFC.DH_L.DH_R.>=0.58 & resultggplot2.6$p.Value<=0.05,
              resultggplot2.6$LFC.DH_L.DH_R.<=0.58 & resultggplot2.6$p.Value<=0.05)***

ggplot(resultggplot2.6, aes(x = LFC.DH_L.DH_R., y = -log10(p.Value))) +  
  
  geom_point(aes(colour = -log10(p.Value))) +
  
  ***scale_color_manual(values=c(??????????))***
  
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Gene.name)) +
  
  ggtitle("Dorsal Horn") +
  
  xlab("log2 fold change") +
  
  ylab("-log10 p-value") +
  
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5), hjust = 0.5),
        
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.25)))

dev.off()
```

The bolded, italicized lines are where I am confused.

Comment: If you have three categories, you should probably use `dplyr::case_when` inside a `mutate`

Comment: @RichardTelford
Is mutate a ggplot2 function? When I tried to input it, I got an error that no such function was found.

Comment: @squashedbannana `mutate()` is in 'dplyr'. I wrote a generic answer below because you have not included data or told how your data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use package 'ggpmisc'. It provides color scales for three-way outcomes and x and y scales for log fold change (including conversion between different log bases) and for *P*-values. The following example from the 'ggpmisc' User Guide should give you a good start.

```r
library(ggpmisc)
library(dplyr)

volcano_example.df %>%
  mutate(., outcome.fct = outcome2factor(outcome)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(logFC, PValue, colour = outcome.fct)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_logFC(name = "Transcript abundance%unit") +
  scale_y_Pvalue() +
  scale_colour_outcome() +
  stat_quadrant_counts(data = . %>% filter(outcome != 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This is a general answer, and the example data has already the outcomes from tests using functions from 'edgeR'. You will need to first compute outcomes expressed as -1, 0, 1 and have a column in your data. You will need to have a look at the help pages to work out how to adjust the code to your data. The data frame used in this examples looks like this:

```r
head(volcano_example.df)
#>         tag     gene outcome       logFC     PValue genotype
#> 1 AT1G01040     ASU1       0 -0.15284466 0.35266997      Ler
#> 2 AT1G01290     ASG4       0 -0.30057068 0.05471732      Ler
#> 3 AT1G01560 ATSBT1.1       0 -0.57783350 0.06681310      Ler
#> 4 AT1G01790   AtSAM1       0 -0.04729662 0.74054263      Ler
#> 5 AT1G02130  AtTRM82       0 -0.14279891 0.29597519      Ler
#> 6 AT1G02560    PRP39       0  0.23320752 0.07487043      Ler
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @squashedbannana Please, have a look at the help pages for 'ggpmisc', within R or at https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/ as a documentation web site.

Comment: This is very helpful; thank you! What is the function of this line: volcano_example.df %>%

What is the .df extension and what does the %>% indicate?

Comment: @squashedbannana
1. `volcano_example.df` is a data frame. The `.df` if my own convention for naming, to R, it is meaningless.
2. `%>%` is a "pipe" operator, just a short-hand  to avoid writing explicitly temporary variables.
`a %>% f1(.) %>% f2(.)`
is a terse equivalent to:
`temp <- f1(a)`
`f2(temp)`